# GitHub deployment to Azure not working

Tags: azure, github

I'm deploying to Azure sites using GitHub, but for some reason I'm not seeing any files insidre the wwwroot folder. It seems like the deployment is not going thur. I do see the files inside the repository folder.

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify what you have done in setting up the deployment. However, the following is what has worked for me:

1. Set the Azure Website for Git Deployment via the following instructions:
   http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/publishing-with-git/
2. Create a GitHub repository
3. Initialize your local working folder in Git. Push to the repo. By the sounds of things, you have done this.
4. Then you need to make sure you link your Azure Website with your GitHub repo. In the Portal, go to the 'Deployments' section of your Azure Website and click:

[image]

If you are logged into GitHub in the same browser it will quickly ask you to specify the correct repository and that'll be it.

This is the step I suspect you either may not have done completely, or perhaps you have selected the wrong repository.

Once it is hooked up, Azure will pull and deploy each time you push a commit to the master branch in the repository.

Comment: Did all this I think it's an issue with Azure